# Inserting data into first empty column cell without creating a new row

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add data to a table, one column at a time. Therefore I don't want to always add a new row, as the column I'm adding to may not have much data in compared to the other columns. As a result I suppose I want to add the data to the first empty cell in the specified column without necessarily adding a new row to the whole table (as there may already be enough rows).

My table has 5 columns.

I'm currently using:

```
$sql=("INSERT INTO [MY_TABLE] ([MY_COLUMN]) VALUES ('[MY_DATA]')");
```

Please could someone assist with the correct code? I know it's basic stuff but I'm new to mySQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see update on duplicate key

Comment: Once you insert a row,Then you need to update a colum using "UPDATE" query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can use `UPDATE` statement with a `WHERE` condition to target that specific row

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = 'whatever' WHERE column_name = '' AND id = '1'
```

If you want to update all rows where that column is blank than simply use

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = 'whatever' WHERE column_name = ''
```

no need of using id in above query

[Reference on UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Comment: Thanks.... UPDATE table_name SET column_name = 'whatever' WHERE column_name = ''  works fine, in that it populates all the empty cells in that column. However using 'AND id = 1' doesn't do anything. Could this be due to the way my table is set up? Also, I assume the 'AND id = 1' is just targeting a specific cell rather than the first one that has matches the criteria?